# How to check if 1 (or more) variables out of a set of variables is equal to a value?

Tags: variables, if-statement, vim

I can't find out how to check if 1 (or more) variables out of a set of variables is equal to a value:

p.e.

```
 let linecurr = getline(endlijn-line)
 let lineabov = getline(endlijn-line-1)

 if  lineabov =~ '[!;:.?]\s*$'
      \ || (lineabov || linecurr) =~ '^\s*$'
      \ || (lineabov || linecurr) =~ '^\s*\(---\|===\)'
 etc.
```

(lineabov || linecurr) --> This doesn't work.

How can I check if 1 (or more) variables out of a set of variables is equal to a value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you want to match against a group of variables. To do this you could create a [list](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#Lists) then see if anything in that lists matches what you want.

```
let l = [ var1, var2, var3, var4 ]
if match(l, "pattern") != -1
    ...
```

[match](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#match%28%29) returns the index of the variable that matched or returns -1 if none matched.

---

See if the first variable has the value you want. If it doesn't check the other variable.

```
(lineabov =~ '^\s*$') || (linecurr =~ '^\s*$')
```

Comment: Yes that's the way I write it normally but I'm curious to know how to combine both variables if the value is the same for both.

Comment: @Remonn Sorry I'm slightly confused. What do you mean by combine both variables.

Comment: @FDnoff, sorry that I'm not clear. I have many variables who have the same value. So I would like to combine these variables as written in my question p.e.: `(variable1 || variable2 || variable3) =~ 'myvalue'`

Comment: @Remonn So you want to check if 1 variable out of your set or variables is equal to a value? (It sounds like you want an array)

Comment: @FDniff, yes, if one ore more of these variables is equal to a value.